# How to avoid multiple "ToLower" in this Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, refactoring, case-insensitive

I am making a call to my database via Linq in which I am trying to filter the data which the database returns.

However, my query is ending up with multiple does not contains check in which each instance of the property has to be separately converted to lower case so that it is case insensitive.

I am not entirely sure if there is a performance impact but if there is a way to better frame the query or to optimize it.

I surely would like to factor that in.

```
var accounts = context.Accounts
                      .Where(x => !x.type.ToLower().Contains("distribution") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("bonus")
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("dividend") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("redemption") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("institutional") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("unclaimed") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("segregated") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("discontinued") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("retail") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("cumulative") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("monthly payment option") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("payout") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("withheld") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains("pf") 
                               && !x.type.ToLower().Contains(" p f "))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? By default the database is not case sensitive.

Comment: Use [the overload of `Contains` that takes a `StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_Char_System_StringComparison_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It is a legacy CE database which has been configured that way - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2008/07/working-with-case-sensitive-sql-compact.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your asserted strings in a collection and take advantage of the linq All method. Something like this:

```cs
private static readonly string[] Filters = new []
{
    "distribution",
    "bonus",
    "dividend",
    "redemption",
    "institutional",
    "unclaimed",
    "segregated",
    "discontinued",
    "retail",
    "cumulative",
    "monthly payment option",
    "payout",
    "withheld",
    "pf",
    " p f "
};

var accounts = context.Accounts.Where(x => Filters.All(f => !x.ToLower().Contains(f)));
```

---

Or more optimized:

```
var accounts = context.Accounts.Where(x => Filters.All(f => !x.Contains(f, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
```